# Cloudflare stops website working as it is enabled

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, dns-hosting, cloudflare

My website is usign Cloudflare to manage its DNS records. I've installed SSL using LetsEncrypt on my website and everything works well when Cloudflare is disabled. As I enable Cloudflare, my website can not be reached anymoer. The SSL configuration status on Cloudflare is in Full (strict) mode.
May you tell me what is the problem for?

Comment: May you show is your web server config?

Comment: Which web server are you using?